# Can we transfer solr indexes from one server to other server instead of reindex

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty

Hi i did a pg dump of data from one server to other. now im having jetty solr indexes which needs to transferred to the other server to avoid reindexing of the whole data and other server contains tomcat solr. if it is possible to transfer indexes guide me how it can be done

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down the first server and then creating a backup of the index directory should be enough. The directory usually have to sub directories, `data` and `conf`. The first contains the index files themselves, while the latter contains the configuration for the core.

This assumes that you're not running in cloud mode with zookeeper etc. In that case following the ["Making and restoring backups" page on the community wiki is probably a good idea](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups). This will be different depending on which version of Solr you're using.

Comment: running with zookeeper, will go through the link thanks. and shutting down cant be done in my case first server is in live

Comment: Be adviced that running under Tomcat isn't officially supported any longer, so you might run into issues with newer versions of Solr without fixes for potential Tomcat issues.